# paper, rock, and scissors in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parse-error

The codes below is programmed to decide the result of paper rock and scissors in Haskell, however terminal give an error

```
data Move = Paper | Rock | Scissors  
 deriving (Eq, Show)
data Result = Win | Draw | Loose 
  deriving (Eq, Show)


beats :: Move -> Move
beats move = case move of 
  Paper -> Scissors
  Rock  -> Paper
  Scissors -> Rock

score :: Move -> Move -> Result
score this_move opposing_move
  | this_move == beats opposing_move = Win
  | this_move == opposing_move       = Draw
  | otherwise = Loose
```

here is the error message from terminal

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:1:60: parse error on input `data'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Who likes to tell me what is wrong with it? Thanks XD

Comment: This is not the cause of your error, but the opposite of `Win` is spelled `Lose`. (“Loose” is the correct spelling of a different word).

Comment: As you've written it here, your code works. What operating system, text editor, and version of ghc are you using? Also, could you find a way to share the exact file you're trying to compile? There might be something subtly wrong with how it is formatted that wasn't preserved when you copied the code here. Further evidence for this is that when I copied your code, the first line doesn't have 60 characters in it, but the error message says that the problem is at the 60th character of the first line.

Comment: If the first line doesn't have 60 char and the error message report the opposite, I understand that the end of line char use in the file format is not the one expected by the compiler. Then the file come surely from a windows system and he haven't being reformat to work on Mac (Linux like) os. It's how I interpret it.

Comment: @zurgl Even with Windows' `\r\n`, there is an `\n`, and the compiler is happy with that. In ancient past, Macs used just `\r` for line separation, and the compiler would have problems with that, probably. But it would be hard to come by such a file today, I think.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Ok I wasn't aware that ghc can manage both case. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is well formed I can load it into ghci without any modification.
The parse error rely on how your text editor manage space and tab.
You should investigate more on your editor configuration than on the correctness of your base code.

---

Use this chunk of code to reformat you file.

```
$ cd /to/your/code.hs
$ ghci
```

and write,

```
ghci >let f = readFile "code.hs"
ghci >do {reencoded <- fmap (filter (/= '\r')) f; writeFile "ncode.hs" reencoded}
```

Then recompile the code.
Let me know if it solve the issue.

As said it should not be enough, but if you enter this instruction into ghci.

```
ghci > readFile "code.hs"
-- print something
```

And you show us the raw result, maybe it could help.

Comment: thx for replying me, im currently using gedit as my edior on mac, do u have any advice on my editor configuration?

Comment: No, I don't know of any problems with that configuration. Could you upload the exact file you're trying to compile?

Comment: Your are on Mac then use vim or gvim, I cannot help you more considering the tool you are using. Take a look at this http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Vim . As Neil pointed out it could be link to eol character too (window eol Vs Linux eol lead to this kind of issue). Anyway the best advice is move to vim IMO.

Comment: lol, i tried to re-type the space in my first line, and :r in terminal, it works , lol, thx man, i love ya